# How do I get Windows 8 to manage my wireless connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

I have a WNA1100 wireless adapter (USB), and a Netgear router, so I was able to set it up just by pressing the button on each once during the drivers install.  It also comes with this golden oldie that wants to manage it.

[image]

In the past, I was able to turn this off by right clicking the connection properties in my network connections folder, then going to the wireless networks tab and clicking the checkbox for "use Windows to configure my wireless network settings".  Now that tab seems to be gone. :(

How can have windows manage my connection instead of this old smart wizard app?  I really want to get rid of this:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just uninstall that Netgear program?

Comment: well that was easy enough.  I didn't think that would work because when I originally installed win8, it wouldn't let me connect to anything unless I used that tool.  You should add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling that Netgear program. Then Windows should take over managing your wireless connections.